# want to list dates from vba code write start date and end date and increse by month

Tags: excel, vba, date

this is my first time to write here ,,, um so glad for that ,

now i have excel file i try to put a start date and end date , and type the dates between this dates in range ... while lest say example

i try to use this code

```
    Sub datetest()


Dim x, y, z, v, a, b As Range

Set x = Cells.Range("k2")
Set y = Cells.Range("l2")
Set z = Cells.Range("m2")
Set v = Cells.Range("n2")
Set a = Cells.Range("o2")
Set b = Cells.Range("p2")



Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date

startDate = DateSerial(x, y, z)
endDate = DateSerial(v, a, b)


Dim i As Integer
i = 1

While startDate <= endDate
    Cells(i, 1) = startDate
    startDate = startDate + 31
    i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

[when i run the code , it type the dates good .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAtlL.jpg)

my problem is now i add 31 day ,, and the dates not come out right ,

i need to edit the code to add month per time , not a day like

```
start date 1-3-2020
end date 1-3-2021
```

the result come out date format `ddd - mmm - yyyy`

```
1-3-2020
1-4-2020
1-5-2020
1-6-2020
1-7-2020
```

and go on till to get to

```
1-3-2021
```

again thanks alot for ur time

Comment: Use [DateAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function) don't just add a number. You can set the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub datetest()


Dim x, y, z, v, a, b As Range

Set x = Cells.Range("k2")
Set y = Cells.Range("l2")
Set z = Cells.Range("m2")
Set v = Cells.Range("n2")
Set a = Cells.Range("o2")
Set b = Cells.Range("p2")



Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date

startDate = DateSerial(x, y, z)
endDate = DateSerial(v, a, b)


Dim i As Integer
i = 1

While startDate <= endDate
    Cells(i, 1) = startDate
    startDate = DateSerial(Year(startDate), Month(startDate) + 1, Day(startDate))
    i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks alot its work prefect , i can't say thanks enough ,,,